# CDF of Piecewise Folded Normal

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I came across a problem in a Carmona's *[Statistical Analysis of Financial Data in R](https://amzn.to/2PMHidP)* (pg. 189, Problem 3.13).  The due date has passed, so now it is considered a self-study question.

---

I am seeking a simple-to-understand proof to the following:

$X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

$X_3 \sim \begin{cases} 
      |X_2| & X_1 \geq 0 \\
      -|X_2| & X_1 < 0 
\end{cases} $

(Q.) Compute the CDF of $X_3$.  State if $X_3$ is Gaussian.

---

Intuitively, I believe $X_3$ should be standard normal $\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  Half of the time, $X_3 = $ folded normal, while half of the time $X_3 = $ negative of a folded normal, by simple symmetry.  I run an `R` simulation to test my suspicions and find this to be correct (the R code and plot is listed at the end of the question).

We know $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 > 0) = \frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry.  We also know:

$\mathbb{P}(|X| \leq x) = \\
\mathbb{P}(-x \leq X \leq x) = \\
\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) - \mathbb{P}(X \leq -x) = \\
\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) - [1 - \mathbb{P}(X \leq x)] = \\
2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) - 1$

So, we try to say $X_3 \sim \frac{1}{2} \cdot [2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) - 1] + \frac{1}{2} \cdot [-2 \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) + 1]$, but the math here does not work out.  Any help from this point would be appreciated.

---

`R` Code and Result

```
# Variables
N <- 1000000
X1 <- rnorm(n=N, mean=0, sd=1); X2 <- rnorm(n=N, mean=0, sd=1)
X3 <- rep(0, N)

# Compute X3
for (i in 1:N) {
  if (X1[i] >= 0) {
    X3[i] <- abs(X2[i])
  } else {
    X3[i] <- -1*abs(X2[i])
  }
}

# Histogram (density)
hist(X3, freq=FALSE, breaks=50, 
     main="Histogram of X3 from Simulation",
     xlab="Value of X3",
     ylab="Density")
# Overlay standard normal for comparison
lines(density(X1), col="blue", lwd=2)
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: $X_3$ has a *mixture distribution*: half the weight is given to a half-normal distribution and the other half of the weight is given to the negative of a half-normal distribution.  Together these two halves describe a Normal distribution, *QED.*  In general, the distribution of $X_3$ consists of the positive portion of the distribution of $X_2$, with weight $\Pr(X_1\ge 0)$, along with the *reflected* version of that positive portion, with the complementary weight.  When $X_2$ is symmetric about $0$ and $X_1$ has probability $1/2$ of being non-negative, $X_3$ has the same distribution as $X_2.$

Comment: Crucial assumption of independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is missing in the question ( which is certainly mentioned in the original source of the problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent of each other in what follows (thanks for pointing out the importance of this go to @stubbornatom.)

I would work directly with the cumulative density function of $X_3$:

$$P(X_3 \leq x) = 0.5[P(|X_2|\leq x) + P(-|X_2| \leq x)]$$

Consider $x \leq 0$.  In this case, $P(|X_2| \leq x) = 0$, so, dropping it from the r.h.s. of the above equation, we have:

$$P(X_3 \leq x) = 0.5P(-|X_2| \leq x) = 0.5[P(X_2 \leq x) + P(-X_2 \leq x)]$$

where the second term on the r.h.s. covers the two cases $X_2 \leq 0$ (in which case $-|X_2| = X_2$) and $X_2 > 0$ (in which case $-|X_2|=-X_2$) respectively.   Multiplying the terms of the last probability by $-1$ and switching the direction of the inequality results in:

$$P(X_3 \leq x) = 0.5[P(X_2 \leq x) + P(X_2 \geq -x)] = P(X_2 \leq x)$$

where the last equality is due to the symmetry of the standard Normal distribution around $0$.

A similar logic can be used to show that $P(X_3 \leq x) = P(X_2 \leq x)$ for the case $x > 0$.  (Actually I think saying "symmetry" is probably sufficient.) 
 Since the CDF of $X_3$ is everywhere equal to the CDF of $X_2$, and $X_2$ is standard Normal, it follows that $X_3$ is standard Normal too.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the detailed, step-by-step solution.

Comment: Didn't we assume that $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom - yes, that's why we can just substitute $0.5$ for $P(X_1 < 0)$ everywhere.

Comment: Was it apparent from the question? That's what I am asking.

Comment: No, it wasn't (+1), but without it you'd be hard-pressed to solve the problem, or so it seems to me.  I'll add your point to the top of the anser, because it is important.